# what is the correct way to explicit instantiation CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp

There are two ways to explicit instantiate CRTP:

1:

```
//base.h-------------------------------------

template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    static void func();
};

//base.cpp--------------------------------
#include "Foo.h"
template<typename T>
void Base<T>::func()
{
}

//derive.h----------------------------------------
#include "base.h"
class Derive : public Base<Derive>
{
public:
};

template class Base<Derive>;  //force explicit instantiation <----
```

Get some warning in visual studio 2017:

> warning C4661: 'void Base::func(void)': no suitable
>   definition provided for explicit template instantiation request

2:

```
//base.h------------------------------------
class Derive;
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    static void func();
};
template class Base<Derive>; //force explicit instantiation <------

//derive.h-------------------------------------
#include "base.h"
class Derive : public Base<Derive>
{
public:
};
```

Get same warning:

> warning C4661: 'void Base::func(void)': no suitable
>   definition provided for explicit template instantiation request

Which one is correct?

Comment: The issue with this isn't CRTP, but that you're trying to explicitly instantiate a template when you don't have all the necessary code. Generally all the code for template classes needs to be in header files.

Comment: @DanielH Thanks. In one of my project, I have to separate the implementation of the template into a separate file.

Comment: Even then, that file is usually still a file that's `#include`d by the template interface header file. To do otherwise would mean that you could only instantiate the template with certain parameters.